# $_GET array not passing to php

Tags: php, html, cakephp, get

I'm having trouble with an HTML form where one of the fields is a multiselect. When I submit the form as POST everything works correctly and I can see and use the array. When submitted as GET, the multiselect portion of the form only shows `string(5) "Array"`.  Literally the word `Array`. I am viewing the query string using CakePHP built in debug kit.

This is the URL

http://www.domain.com/?keywords=&location%5B%5D=12333&location%5B%5D=42123

The important part here being the location array. But when I look at the server variables it changes to:

```
Query String keywords=&location=Array
```

Here `location` just prints the word `Array`. No matter what I try I cannot pass the location array to PHP. is there a setting in the `php.ini` to allow this? Is there another way to make this work properly? I need this to be a GET query for the purposes of saving searches.

`var_dump` of `$_GET` (slightly different query than above):

```php
array(10) {
    ["agent"]=> string(0) ""
    ["price_min"]=> string(1) "0"
    ["price_max"]=> string(9) "987654321"
    ["beds"]=> string(0) ""
    ["baths"]=> string(0) ""
    ["mls"]=> string(0) ""
    ["pool"]=> string(1) "0"
    ["spa"]=> string(1) "0"
    ["keywords"]=> string(0) ""
    ["location"]=> string(5) "Array"
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: What does the string representation of a PHP  array that is URL encoded look like?  Maybe use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)... but really, sounds like you should look at sending a POST.  Or if array not too complicated break it out to key/pair values like GET looks for.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$_GET` variable. That's what `$this->request->data` and `$this->request->query` is for. Try using `debug($this->request->query)`

Comment: I am using &this->request->query. I used get to debug as its not processed by cake

Answer (score 5):

```
location%5B%5D=12333&location%5B%5D=42123
        ^^^^^^               ^^^^^^
```

You're using the `location[]` naming convention for the form fields, which tells PHP to create an ARRAY of values in the superglobals. This means you actually have this kind of structure:

```
$_GET = array(
   'keywords' => '',
   'location' => array(12333, 42123)
);
```

An array in string context is the literal word `Array`:

```
echo $_GET['location'];    // outputs: Array
echo $_GET['location'][0]; // outputs: 12333
```

Comment: I read the question as the reverse... thought was array cast to string..."Array"

Comment: echo $_GET['location'][0]; // outputs: A
echo $_GET['location'][1]; // outputs: r
echo $_GET['location'][2]; // outputs: r
echo $_GET['location'][3]; // outputs: a
echo $_GET['location'][4]; // outputs: y

Comment: Marc B you don't leave a question for me to answer haha :)

Comment: Amen @MohamedBelal.  Rymn.  Try a var_dump() on $_GET;